# performance impact of making where clause dummy - SQL Server

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, where-clause

I need to know about the performance impact of the below method of writing the query. 
Assume there is an employee table. Requirement is to get a list of employees under a particular department and optionally the user can filter the result set by providing the city/location.

```
declare @dept varchar(10) = 'ABC', @city varchar(10) 
select * from employee where dept = @dept and city = isnull(@city, city)
```

Is this fine? or do we need to use traditional if logic to check whether the user provided city as input?

Thanks,
Sabarish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere that the following syntax is quicker than calling ISNULL():

```
select * from employee where dept = @dept and (@city IS NULL OR @city = city)
```

It was something to do with the SQL compiler effectively knowing that it can ignore the expression in brackets if @city is null.

Sorry but no idea where I read this (it was some time ago), otherwise I would cite it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Most powerfull aproach to solve performance problems with nulls is try to avoid nulls by default values. In your case should be good try something like:

```
declare @dept varchar(10) = 'ABC', @city varchar(10) = 'unknown' 
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE dept = @dept AND 
      @city = 'unknown'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE dept = @dept AND 
      city = @city AND 
      @city != 'unknown'
```

Why?
Cardinality estimator is not able to estimate correct number of rows that query returns and it causes, that execution plan should be bad for this particular query. Avoid nulls and everything will be great B-)

Answer (score 0):

For sure the answer provided by @Jonathan will improve performance if 'City' column has separate NonClustered Index on it. If not both the execution plan will lead to SCAN. If you have NonClustered Index then the Jonathan's approach will do SEEK instead of SCAN which will be good in terms of performance.

Let me try to explain why that is the scenario with a sample as in below table: For ease of use I did not considered two predicates dept and city instead I am considering only City.

Consider below Employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Dept] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](15) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Creating Clustered Index on Id
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_Employee_EmployeeId] ON [dbo].[Employee] ( [EmployeeId] ASC)

--Loading Data
```

Loading Sample data

```
Insert into Employee 
    Select top (10000)  EmployeeId = Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL))
            ,EmployeeName = Concat ('Name ',Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL)))
            ,Dept = Concat ('Dept ',(Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL))) % 50)
            ,City = Concat ('City ',Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL)))
            from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
```

Now Executing simple query with normal predicate:

```
Declare @city varchar(15) = 'City 1500'
Select * from Employee where city = @city
--It Does Clustered Index Scan
```

[image: Clustered Index Scan as no index on city]

Now creating an non-clustered Index on city

```
--Now adding Index on City
Create NonClustered Index NCI_Employee_City on dbo.Employee (city)

Declare @city varchar(15) = 'City 1500'
Select * from Employee where city =  @city
--It Does Index Seek
```

[image: Index Seek due to non-clustered index]

Now coming to your isnull function
Since it forces function on each city it uses SCAN as below

```
Declare @city varchar(15) = 'City 1500'
Select * from Employee where city =  isnull(@city, City)
go
Declare @city varchar(15) = 'City 1500'
Select * from Employee where city is null or city = @city
```

[image: IsNull vs or condition]

If you look at the overall percentage it takes more for IsNull function.

So if you have an Index all these will be helpfull else it is going to be scan anyway.